# Display students of specific age using struct

Tags: c++

My task for uni is to create a program using structures. In this program I have to make an entry of students, their name, birth date and group (a random number). And I have to search the students according to the input age.

Please note that I am still learning :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
char name[50];
int year;
int group;

};

int main( )
{
int N;
int age;

cout<<"Enter how many entries:";
cin>>N;
struct student student1[N];

for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
cout<<"enter the student's name:";
cin>>student1[i].name;
cout<<"enter the birth year:";
cin>>student1[i].year;
cout<<"enter the group:";
cin>>student1[i].group;
}
cout<<"enter the student's age:";
cin>>age;

if (age==2016-student1[N].year)
{
    cout<<"The student with the age "<<age<<" is:";
    cout<<student1[N].name;
    cout<<student1[N].group;
}
else
{
    cout<<"the student wasn't found.";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: @krista this code appears to be broken. In particular, the line `if (age==2016-student1[N].year)` is broken, as `student1[N]` was neither allocated nor assigned. It appears the search functionality is missing (you probably want to wrap that `if` inside a loop).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstring>
```

You're not using any of the features in that header. Replace is with `<string>` and *do* use those. Also indent your code, it makes it more readable.

```
struct student
{
  std::string name;
  int year;
  int group;
};
```

Don't get into the habit of using this:

```
using namespace std;
```

See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

```
int N;
int age;
```

You only need `N` a few lines down, and `age` only way below inside the loop. Declare them as close to their first use as possible, in the smallest scope possible.

```
cin>>N;
struct student student1[N];
```

A few issues:

- You're not checking whether that read of an `int` actually worked (same for all the other inputs).
- You don't need the `struct` keyword there. You need it in C where `struct`s live in a separate namespace, but that's not the case in C++.
- This is not standard C++: this uses a feature called variable-length arrays which are standard C but not part of C++ (but some compilers have support for it anyway). Instead, use a `std::vector` (don't forget to `#include <vector>` also).

```
return 0;
```

This isn't necessary, if `main` doesn't explicitly return anything, the standard guarantees that it will act as if it had returned 0. (This is *only* valid for the `main` function, all other non-void functions must return something on all their returning branches.)